# Need help to install WebSphere Application Server V8.5

Tags: installation, websphere

I have downloaded the bellow rar file from IBM site. But I dont know how to install. Please advice me how can I install this  WebSphere Application Server V8.5.

Answer (score 3):

The InfoCenter is your best friend when asking questions about most IBM products.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp

The installation guide you want should be there.

Answer (score 1):

since WebSphere 8.0 the default install process should be done using IBM Installation manager.

IM FAQ: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/installmgr/faq.html
Download latest IM from: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032358

After that all you have to do is launch the Installation Manager and point a repository to your WebSphere download directory. IM will than have a step by step wizard that will guide you  through the installation process.